# AWS Glue Crawler and JDCBConnection : "Expected string length >= 1, but found 0 for params.Targets.JdbcTargets[0].customJdbcDriverClassName"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I am trying to setup an AWS Glue Crawler using a JDBC connection in order to populate my AWS Glue Data Catalog databases.
I already have a Connection which passes the test but when I submit my crawler creation, I have this error : `"Expected string length >= 1, but found 0 for params.Targets.JdbcTargets[0].customJdbcDriverClassName"` as you can see in the first screenshot.
[image]

The only clue I have for now is that there is no Class Name attached to my connection. However I cannot edit it while editing the connection
[image]

Does it ring a bell to someone?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Incidently, I am also trying to do something similar and facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you also trying with a postgres connection?

Comment: yes its postgres for me as well....i will now try what Lucas has answered.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this issue, and even tried using aws-cli to create/update my connection to try to manually input the required parameter.

Turns out this is an AWS UI issue caused by a recent update. According to [this post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUqQnaZ2KsTuSub_jZ5oKxkA/cannot-create-or-update-a-crawler-with-expected-string-length-1-but-found-0) you can create it using the Legacy console for now (on the sidbar, there is a Legacy section where you can find the Legacy pages). I just tried it on my end and it worked =)